# Delete TeamCity Audit Log Entries?

Tags: logging, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

How do I delete entries in the audit log? There is sensitive information that got entered and is able to be viewed in the compare feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this sensitive information is in the build configuration history, you'll see the files containing the history with the same filename as the main config with a numbered file extension, in `$TeamCityData/config/projects/{project_name}/buildTypes`. The previous version will be in `.1`, previous to that will be in `.2`, TeamCity renames all the files when you save the config. You can just delete the history, or edit it out of the history and keep the rest.

For example:

- `bt123.xml`
- `bt123.xml.1`
- `bt123.xml.2`
- `bt123.xml.3`

If the sensitive information isn't in the build configuration history you should find the config file for where it is an edit/delete it.

A point of fair warning, this sensitive information may have been leaked within your organisation, if it is a password you should reset it.

Comment: Also `xml` files under `$TeamCityDatar/system/pluginData/audit/configHistory/buildTypes/`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the row(s) from `audit_additional_object` & `comments` table from database if you really want to delete the audit entries.